# How to launch an iOS simulator app from the command line

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, simctl

Is there a way to launch an app on the iOS simulator from the command line, like

```
simctl launch <app-package>
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

To install your app:
xcrun simctl install booted

To launch the app:
xcrun simctl launch booted

Hope this helps.